# Making ahref from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div as follows:

```
        <div class="slide_items">
            <div class="slide_item"><a href="/url"><img src="image"/></a></div>
            <div class="slide_title"><a href="/url">title</a></div>
        </div>
```

What i want to do is, instead of having URL in each item in `slide_items` div. I want user to click on `<div class="slide_items">`. I want the `slide_items` to be clickable as the div itself, rather than putting a href in every inner div.

How can i do this?

Comment: Note that this would remove functionality, such as middle/right clicking the link, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *proper* way would be to use a single link (*but change the inner elements to `span` for validness*)

```
    <a href="/url" class="slide_items">
        <span class="slide_item"><img src="image"/></span>
        <span class="slide_title">title</span>
    </a>
```

And make sure that they are treated as `block` elements from the css

```
a.slide_items, a.slide_items span{
    display:block;
}
```

---

If you ***have*** to go the div way, then use

```
<div class="slide_items" data-href="/url">
    <div class="slide_item"><img src="image"/></div>
    <div class="slide_title">title</div>
</div>
```

and add a script (*since you use jquery*)

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide_items').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).data('href');
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onclick="window.open('google.com')"` event to simulate a link to your div.

In the case where you want the entire div to appear to a be a link, you will want to change your cursor.  Add `style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;"` to your div as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onclick` property to the `div`:

```
<div class="slide_items" onclick="location.href='/url';" >
    <div class="slide_item"><img src="image"/></div>
    <div class="slide_title">title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="slide_items">
        <div class="slide_item"><img src="image" alt="my image" /></div>
        <divclass="slide_title">title</div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slide_items').click(function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    });
});
```

css:

```
.slide_items:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/68Smw/6/

The redirect isn't working in jsfiddle, but it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some simple javascript to get this done

use the onclick() event

so your HTML code looks something like

```
<div class="slide_items">
            <div class="slide_item" onclick="function1()"><img src="image"/></div>
            <div class="slide_title" onclick="function2()">title</div>
        </div>
```

your javascript code will look like

```
function function1(){
// insert your code here
}

function function2()
{
// insert your code here
}
```

the code can be done in many ways depending on what you want  , if you just want to redirect to another div , use the `display` attributes alternating between `none` and `block` , more reference here [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)  .

if you want to redirect to another site you can use

```
window.open("your url")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to likley say: Click here to enter site:

```
<div>

<a href="YOUR PAGE HERE!">Click here to enter my site!</a> 

</div>
```